# How to add a variable to URL of $.ajax({ url : " "});

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url, input

I want the user to be able to change a part of the URL address to their post code. I have a text box and button which I am hoping will submit the value to the URL.

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.ajax({ 
        url : "http://SomeAddress.com/" + PostCode + ".json",
        dataType : "jsonp",
        success : function(parsed_json) {
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="GetPostCode" />
<button id="SetPostCode">Set This Post Code</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#SetPostCode").click(function() {
    var PostCode = document.getElementById("GetPostCode").value;
    $("#GetPostCode").val(" ");
    return false;
});
```

I understand that the line

```
$.ajax({ 
    url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/2508132ae0c7601a/geolookup/conditions/q/UK/" + PostCode + ".json",
```

does not work that way, but I didn't know what else to do. Could someone please show me what I need to do in order for this to work?

Comment: The only reason that wouldn't work were if PostCode wasn't global.. If it was your sorted

Comment: Why don't you do the `$.ajax` after the line `var PostCode` inside the click handler?

Comment: +1 @CarlSaldanha You set your `PostCode` variable in the click function therefore, you can't access it from other places.

Comment: Well that was simple... Thanks Guys

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

   var PostCode=1;
   $.ajax({ url : "http://SomeAddress.com/"+PostCode +".json",
   dataType : "jsonp"
   //.... more stuff
  });


  $("#SetPostCode").click(function() {
     PostCode = document.getElementById("GetPostCode").value;
     $("#GetPostCode").val(" ");
     return false; 
  });

});
```

Above would work as PostCode is now global to the jQuery and can be accessed anywhere

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Do you know how to save this value in a cookie so that it is what they set every time they refresh the page?